# AVG function using mongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have written this in MongoDB:

```
db.sponsors.aggregate([{"$group" : {_id:"$idspons", count:{$sum:1}}}])
```

In this way, I obtain for each id how many times they appear in my database:

```
{ "_id" : "01", "count" : 87 }
{ "_id" : "02", "count" : 6 }
{ "_id" : "03", "count" : 18 }
{ "_id" : "04", "count" : 152 }
{ "_id" : "05", "count" : 96 }
{ "_id" : "06", "count" : 28 }
{ "_id" : "07", "count" : 74 }
```

I want to do the average of this count (so that my output would be 65,85 ). How can I do?

Comment: Is there something in the provided answer that you believe does not address your question? If so then please comment on the answer to clarify what exactly needs to be addressed that has not. If it does in fact answer the question you asked then please note to [Accept your Answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to the questions you ask

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
db.sponsors.aggregate([{$group:{"_id":"_id", AverageValue: { $avg: "$count" }}}])
```

Comment: it returns  { "_id" : "_id", "AverageValue" : null }

Answer (score 0):

- `$group` by null and do average of count using `$avg`,

```
db.sponsors.aggregate([
  { "$group": { _id: "$idspons", count: { $sum:1 } } },
  { "$group": { _id: null, averageCount: { $avg: "$count" } } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CET9VclrcFp)